# How to automatically expand contents on a JSON web page?

Tags: firefox, javascript, json

I use **QuoDB** to find useful examples from movie scripts. It seems like a JSON web page and I'm looking for a way to get the [results](http://www.quodb.com/search/%22even%20so%22?&titles_per_page=5&phrases_per_title=5) expanded without having to click on every "context" button. Is there a way like entering a JavaScript code on the address bar or maybe finding out a URL parameter which can make those results expanded?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to do it is right click > inspect element > select the "Network" tab > highlight the "XHR" filter > Reload the page. You will now be able to see all the API calls that come through.

EDIT

If you download an application called [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) you can use it to do GET requests.

Search API: http://api.quodb.com/search/"ENTER SEARCH HERE"?titles_per_page=5&phrases_per_title=5&page=1

And if you want to get the context you can the results for the search API to get quotes by using the "title_id" and the "phrase_id" like so:
http://api.quodb.com/quotes/title_id/phrase_id

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not that technical. Can you give me a url  template for that site which I can replace my searches in that url and get the results with expanded context? Besides, I followed the steps and found something like this when I click on the context
http://api.quodb.com/quotes/M1295236bf/12592019
I put that in the address bar but it returns some gibberish text.

Comment: If you read my answer and give it a go, you will understand this is not a technical process. It is very simple to do.

Comment: The closest thing I get was the url template which I gave in the above comment. There is two problem: 
1. I load that url from address bar, but the text is not usable. 
2. You need to find out all the "title_id" and the "phrase_id" one by one. 
I'm looking for a way to load all the context for a search at once. You said it's simple, I'll be very much appreciated if you could screen cast doing that and share it here too.